# How to fit an image in various different shapes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, texture

So im making CSGO skin for AUG in photoshop,i want image (the "steel") to fit in the green shape that i selected,how can i do that?
[image: AUG Skin]

Comment: Hi Dr.Sheldon-Memer, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: @AndrewH I was trying to fit the steel 2 hours nothing worked....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the piece you want to turn to steel isolated, there are several ways of achieving that:

1. First option is to create a selection based on the shape layer (CTRL + Click on its preview) then make a mask out of the steel layer (the button for this is at the bottom of the layer panel). The steel layer will have to be on top of and completely covering the shape layer (imagine you are placing a sticker on a piece of metal). This means you'll need to scale it up (CTRL + T).
2. The preferred approach is to simply have the steel layer on top of the shape layer, and then while holding the ALT key, clicking in between them (you'll get a special arrow cursor). What this does is force the steel layer on top to fit the shape underneath it. You can still move it around, transform or edit it afterwards.

For both of these options you have to have the shape layer (the one you circled) isolated and having a transparent background, which I assume you did since you said you selected it.

Comment: Happy to help :).